# control a resistor connection in the circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-design

I am trying to use a function on a charging chip where disconnecting(floating) a  pin usually connected through a resistor to ground, disables charging ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24030.pdf), section 10.3.8). In the default state the pin is connected to ground through the resistor:
[image]
[image]
I could either use a NPN transistor as a low side switch, ie between the resistor and ground and control it through an mcu. Or I could get an spst switch. 
Is this the right way to achieve expected behavior(floating the pin on demand)? there any another(more efficient/cheaper) way to do this?

Comment: Could you please clarify **which** pin you mean that is "usually connected through a resistor to ground". It saves some digging in the datasheet.

Comment: I suggest that you make a screenshot of that part of the datasheet and include it in the question. I'm not going to to open a link and search for some section. Also nowhere in your question does it say what IC you're talking about. Include the type number in your text and make that a link to the datasheet.

Comment: Sorry, I thought mentioning the datasheet section and providing link was enough. I have updated the question with a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The section you mentioned in the datasheet gives a couple of alternatives:

> If the DPPM pin is floated (resistor disconnected) then the DPPM pin will be driven high and the charge current will go to zero. Note that this applies to both AC and USB charging.
>
> Another way to disable the charging is to externally drive the DPPM pin high (to the OUT pin voltage).

You could insert a series transistor as you mention in the question. I would prefer not to add components into the signal path that could affect operation (at least not without calculating their effect), so the second option to drive the DPPM pin high sounds simpler. You could use a PMOS to do the connection. You might want to use an NMOS + pull up resistor to control the PMOS gate to make sure it is fully turned off when not needed, not looking like a parallel resistor to Vout (this would happen if the microcontroller voltage is lower than Vout).

Comment: so sounds like it can be done with an MCU gpio pin?